# Updating JSON values based on product quantities purchased

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a shopping cart in javascript, which is linked to a .json api calling products data. The object is named 'products' and each product has a 'countInStock' property with a value.

Is it possible to create a function which updates (decrements based on items purchased) the .json file's 'countInStock' property for the relevant products after the user clicks a button?
Where it could be a multiple products being purchased in the cart or a single product.

This is the code currently being used for the cart:

```
import { parseRequestUrl, rerender } from '../utils';
import { getProduct } from '../api';
import { getCartItems, setCartItems } from '../localStorage';

const addToCart = (item, forceUpdate = false) => {
  let cartItems = getCartItems();
  const existItem = cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
  if (existItem) {
    if (forceUpdate) {
      cartItems = cartItems.map((x) =>
        x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
      );
    }
  } else {
    cartItems = [...cartItems, item];
  }
  setCartItems(cartItems);
  if (forceUpdate) {
    rerender(CartScreen);
  }
};
const removeFromCart = (id) => {
  setCartItems(getCartItems().filter((x) => x.product !== id));
  if (id === parseRequestUrl().id) {
    document.location.hash = '/cart';
  } else {
    rerender(CartScreen);
  }
};

const CartScreen = {
  after_render: () => {
    const qtySelects = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-select');
    Array.from(qtySelects).forEach((qtySelect) => {
      qtySelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        const item = getCartItems().find((x) => x.product === qtySelect.id);
        addToCart({ ...item, qty: Number(e.target.value) }, true);
      });
    });
    const deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-button');
    Array.from(deleteButtons).forEach((deleteButton) => {
      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeFromCart(deleteButton.id);
      });
    });
    document.getElementById('checkout-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.location.hash = '/signin';
    });
  },
  render: async () => {
    const request = parseRequestUrl();
    if (request.id) {
      const product = await getProduct(request.id);
      addToCart({
        product: product._id,
        name: product.name,
        image: product.image,
        price: product.price,
        countInStock: product.countInStock,
        qty: 1,
      });
    }
    const cartItems = getCartItems();
    return `
    <div class="content cart">
      <div class="cart-list">
        <ul class="cart-list-container">
          <li>
            <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
            <div>Price</div>
          </li>
          ${
            cartItems.length === 0
              ? '<div>Cart is empty. <a href="/#/">Go Shopping</a>'
              : cartItems
                  .map(
                    (item) => `
            <li>
              <div class="cart-image">
                <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}" />
              </div>
              <div class="cart-name">
                <div>
                  <a href="/#/product/${item.product}">
                    ${item.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                  Qty: 
                  <select class="qty-select" id="${item.product}">
                  ${[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) =>
                    item.qty === x + 1
                      ? `<option selected value="${x + 1}">${x + 1}</option>`
                      : `<option  value="${x + 1}">${x + 1}</option>`
                  )}  

                  </select>
                  <button type="button" class="delete-button" id="${
                    item.product
                  }">
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-price">
                $${item.price}
              </div>
            </li>
            `
                  )
                  .join('\n')
          } 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-action">
          <h3>
            Subtotal (${cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items)
            :
            $${cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
          </h3>
          <button id="checkout-button" class="primary fw">
            Proceed to Checkout
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
  },
};

export default CartScreen;
```

Just some of the JSON code:

```
module.exports = {
    products: [
        {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'Intel Core i5 11600k',
            category: 'cpu',
            image: '/images/intel i5.jpg',
            price: 399.99,
            brand: 'Intel',
            countInStock: 6,
        },
        {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'Intel Core i7 11700k',
            category: 'cpu',
            image: '/images/intel i7.jpg',
            price: 399.99,
            brand: 'Intel',
            countInStock: 13,
        },
        {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'Intel Core i9 11900k',
            category: 'cpu',
            image: '/images/intel i9.jpg',
            price: 549.99,
            brand: 'Intel',
            countInStock: 10,
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need a getter / setter on your cart or inventory object. Here's a basic example that might help, albeit a bit contrived.  You might want to read up on JSON requires in node.js if that's your platform or simply JSON.parse if you have some JSON as a string, but basically the important thing is that you get the JSON into a proper Object so you can get or set the value of the inventory ( or any other property for that matter ).  Then you can work out a function that will update that prop, either directly on the the object itself or a perhaps even in an immutable way if you want to go there.  Basically, there are several ways to implement something like that and none of them are necessarily wrong or right.

```js
const pathToJSON = './foo/bar.json';

const inventory = { stock: 42 } || require(pathToJSON);

const inventoryObject = Object(inventory);

inventoryObject.increase = function(i) {
    this.stock = (this.stock + i);
}

console.log(inventory.stock); // 42
inventory.increase(2)
console.log(inventory); // 44
```

Plus the fiddle if you want to play around with it yourself https://jsfiddle.net/bqajok8s/

Comment: would this work for individual countInStock or would this only work if there was a single stock count for all the products?

Comment: you could do the same thing for each count in stock or at least create a function that takes the count in stock as an argument.  try a few things and see what you're happy with.